# Do users like icons on an input field?

Tags: user-behavior, icons, user-expectation, input-fields

**Icons on input field**

[image: Three input fields with icons: Email Address, Password, Confirm Password]

**Input field without icons**

[image: Three input fields without icons: First name, Last name, Email address]

Do icons really matter on an input field? Do they encourage users signing up?

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21418/is-it-better-to-have-an-icon-in-front-of-validation-messages/21419 quite related, might be useful...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the icons exactly (or as near possible) confer the ideas and concepts of a form's box, they are greatly beneficial to rapidity of viewer comprehension.

Good/Great icons provide another more subjective quality, that of endearment and apparent consideration (demonstrated empathy) of and to the time/rate of the user's digestion and ease of familiarity with the functions and purposes of elements/forms etc.

Unfortunately there's no objective way to absolutely say that an icon is absolutely the best and most effective of its type and for its purpose. Although I think it can be safely and assuredly said that the example you show works quite well.

If this is your situation, I suggest you use these types of icons with stylistic considerations appropriate to your site/environment.

Comment: 'they are greatly beneficial to rapidity of viewer comprehension' - What research are you drawing from to suggest that a text field based icon improves comprehension?

Comment: I'm sorry. I assumed it was obvious.

Comment: “I assumed it was obvious.” – Prime mistake in UX and communication.

Comment: @Crissov ...by those who've self selected and/or been appointed inappropriately.

Answer (score -2):

The best answer would be '**Ask Yourself**'.

When you drive car, Do you want to read  Road Signals in written text?

Probably Not. Because it will take time and you should be focused on the road.

So, Red, Yellow and Green colors are simple enough to convey the meaning of signals.

Arrow signs are quite simple than 'TURN RIGHT' or 'DO NOT TRY TO OVERTAKE' (by the time you read, you .. you know)

Likewise, People are tired of reading the same sentences all over the Internet. 'Enter your name', 'email address' etc..

But, when you see a Kid's head, You get the idea that this field is asking for nickname and a Locker image is nothing but the Password field.

And most importantly. Pictures attract more than text.
( for example, 'Like' text or 'Heart' icon. Which one will you prefer for your Instagram pics? ) I like <3<3<3

Comment: This answer is almost entirely contrary to nearly all research and core knowledge within usability. The idea "just ask yourself" is where poor usability starts. You are not the user. The notion that color has universal meaning is false. The statement that "people are tired of reading the same sentence" is amazingly blunt without any supporting evidence. The notion that an icon plants the same, and correct, idea in everyone's head is easily shown to be completely inaccurate.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey I think asking yourself the question is important, if only to try and establish whether you have enough of the same thinking and requirements as the end-user and if you are making assumptions that are not true. As with any type of testing, how you validate the assumptions you make will go a long way towards improving the design. I think asking yourself is part of an bigger process and not completely irrelevant.

Comment: @MichaelLai - Yes, I absolutely agree. The answer however, in my opinion, is phrased in a way that what your own answer, as a designer, is the "right" answer. It can certainly be a piece of the process, but is certainly not the end-point. Other aspects of the answer are also clearly not accurate.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey I understand the point that you are making, which is why I wanted to add this comment to the answer to encourage the person to consider their answer further.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey "This answer is almost entirely contrary to nearly all research and core knowledge within usability." Can you cite ANY of this research? Can you also demonstrate that it's the majority findings of all research?

Comment: Yes, I can. [You are not like your user](http://uxmyths.com/post/715988395/myth-you-are-like-your-users), [icons not enhancing usability](http://uxmyths.com/post/715009009/myth-icons-enhance-usability), and [the cultural differences of color meaning](http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/colours-in-cultures/) are all basic notions in usability. Not to mention that large amounts of automotive usability, such as road signs, do not translate to web sites. If you're unsure of the above you can ask a new question or ask in chat, as SE comments are not for extended discussions.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey The title 'icons not enhancing usability' is simply false.
icons without labels make usability worse - that is true. 
But inputs usually have labels - at least they should.
And icons really help the readability of multiple inputs.
Since many designers use the same icons for input fields like email, user, password -
these icons are recognizable and enhance user experience.